# Is it possible on that +1 be seen only by the owner of the post in Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

So when I put +1 on someone’s post on Google+, is it possible that only the person which shared it can see my +1?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only if the person has shared it privately. If post has been shared publicly, its not possible.